# Why is addEventListener not working when creating a HTML element with createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

So in my code im creating a simple div and adding an event listener

```js
const new_card = document.createElement('div');
new_card.className = 'card';
new_card.style.left = e.pageX + "px"
new_card.style.top = e.pageY + "px"
new_card.addEventListener('onclick', handler);
```

Code for the handler:

```js
const handler = (event) => {
    if ((event.target as HTMLElement).parentElement!.className == 'card') {
        get_selected_card((event.target as HTMLElement));
    }
};
```

and then the handler call this function:

```js
function get_selected_card(elmnt: HTMLElement | null) {
    console.log(elmnt);
};
```

but the code isnt working, i got no response in my console

Comment: Are you sure you are not using `innerHTML` anywhere in the project? How do you insert this element into the dom?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski innerHTML, no, but i dont know if thats related to document.createElement

Comment: Using `innerHTML` on any of the ancestors of that element will clear event listeners. How do you insert `new_card ` element into the dom?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski appendChild(element)

Comment: Isn't the event name supposed to be [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event), not `onclick`?

Comment: when you use `addEventListener`, you don't use the `on` prefix. It's just `new_card.addEventListener('click', handler)`.

Comment: @Steve OMG!!! that was the problem, thanks, so does other events like mousedown have different names when using addEventListener and defining them inline?

Comment: Yep, they usually (always?) have slightly different names when directly accessing them via an element (like `element.onclick`) versus with `addEventListener`.

Comment: Steve, you should put your comment in the form of an answer